# Installing APC on Centos 6 package dependency issues - Which direction should I proceed

Tags: nginx, centos6.4, alternative-php-cache, drupal7

I have a CentOS 6.4 x32 VPS running NGINX and Drupal 7. To improve response I would like to install and configure APC. To do this my first attempt was to install it using PECL. To start I fired this command

```
yum install php-pear php-devel httpd-devel
```

(This is because pear requires phpize which is available in devel which inturn depends on apxs which is available in the httpd-devel package.) I got the following error.

```
Error: Package: php-devel-5.3.3-27.el6_5.i686 (updates)
Requires: php(x86-32) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
Installed: php-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.i686 (@remi)
php(x86-32) = 5.4.23-1.el6.remi
Available: php-5.3.3-26.el6.i686 (base)
php(x86-32) = 5.3.3-26.el6
Available: php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.i686 (updates)
php(x86-32) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am not sure which direction I should be taking 1) should I downgrade php 5.4 to php 5.3 or 2) should I look for php-devel 5.4 ?

During the course of my research I found a post that mentioned apc can be installed using yum. so i ran this command
    yum install php-pecl-apc
and got a whole bunch of dependency issues
    Error: Package: php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.i686 (base)
    Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Installed: php-common-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.i686 (@remi)
    php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-32
    Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.i686 (base)
    php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.i686 (updates)
    php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.i686 (base)
    Requires: php(api) = 20090626
    Installed: php-common-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.i686 (@remi)
    php(api) = 20100412-x86-32
    Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.i686 (base)
    php(api) = 20090626
    Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.i686 (updates)
    php(api) = 20090626
    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

This error is similar to the one in the first case and I am unsure which way to go. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've installed php from remi Repo, so you should install php-devel and php-pear from remi as well in order to get the correct package version.

```
yum install php-devel php-pear --enablerepo=remi
```